# Scale of 0-1 change it to 1-180?

Tags: calculus

I have a range of number that are coming in from 0 - 1
for example:
0.178
0.45
0.89
0.41

The highest they can go is 1.0

I would like to convert these into a scale going from 1 - 180

So if the number that came in was 0.5

Comment: Let $x \in [0,1]$. Then $y = 179x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are looking for an *affine* transformation of the variable $0 \le x \le 1$ to some other domain $a \le y \le b$.

The general form of this is

$$y = (b-a)x + a$$

In your case, $b = 180$, $a = 1$, so you get, as Joshua said in his comment,

$$y = 179x+1.$$

This works for all $b > a$, but if you have $x$ defined in some other interval, you have to be more careful!